# JQUERY if :last:visible

Tags: jquery, visible

```
if( $("div:last").is(":visible") ) {
    $("p").css("color", "red");
}
```

why the script don't work correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/8Rrm2/8/

Comment: Well, it's not visible. Your css has `display:none;` rule for all divs.

Comment: There is no paragraph "p" tag in your fiddle code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script only checks if its visible at the time of running. It doesn't check if it is *ever* visible. So when the user uses the right arrow key to make it visible, the script has already passed and it remains not-red. You would have to move that logic into your event handler.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XNQk6/) is a working fiddle. All I did was cut and paste your logic.

Now, every time the user presses an arrow key, it updates the button and changes the color appropriately.

Also, just FYI: [KnockoutJS](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) has some amazing tools for model-binding. With almost no scripting, you can have a model and view-model automatically update each other.  The arrow key updates your view-model value, which in turn automatically creates changes in your view. It's really worth looking into, and their tutorials are quite fun.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzump/4/) is an example of your script, modified to work with Knockout, in case you're curious. In this example, its not a *ton* less code, but I do think its a little cleaner to read and to handle "exceptional cases". For example, if you wanted it to be red on values 2, 5, and 7, it just requires changing the one function called `iAmRed`.